# Why need emit socket event again in nextjs

Tags: next.js, socket.io

I try to do socket communitcation between clients in nextjs.

In every turital (for example this: https://blog.logrocket.com/implementing-websocket-communication-next-js/) need emit socket event twice:

For example:

```
First:
socket.emit('input-change', e.target.value)

io.on('connection', socket => {
//Here I recive data and emit it again, why?
  socket.on('input-change', msg => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('update-input', msg)
  })
})
```

and finaly I get this event:

```
socket.on('update-input', msg => {...})
```

Why I can't send and recive events without this:

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
//Here we recive data and emit again, why?
  socket.on('input-change', msg => {
    socket.broadcast.emit('update-input', msg)
  })
})
```

Just send in a component:

```
socket.emit('input-change', e.target.value)
```

and just recieve in another my component:

```
socket.on('input-change', msg => {...})
```